# Javascript: Calling a function in an object literal

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I'm learning to program in Javascript and I'd like some help/clarification.

I declared an array that contains animal names. I defined a function that I use to split a string in two. Then I create an empty object literal and add an animal and corresponding breed. I'm trying to invoke the separateWords function in the object literal, but I need some clarification. Here's my code:

```
var myPets = ["Bengal Bobcat", "Beagle"];

var separateWords = function (string) {
    return string.split(" ");
};

var nameCollection = {};
nameCollection.cat = separateWords(myPets[0]);  
nameCollection.dog = myPets[1];
nameCollection.fish = null;
```

When I enter console.log(nameCollection) I get the following:

```
Object {cat: Array[2], dog: “Beagle”, fish: null}
cat: Array[2]
0: "Bengal"
1: "Bobcat"
length: 2
```

However, when I enter console.log( separateWords(myPets[0])), I see:

```
[“Bengal”, “Bobcat”]
```

I don’t understand why the value of cat shows up as Array[2].

Comment: That's just how the console does it. It is still an array with 2 items, that you can inspect further.

Comment: if you click on the `Array` word it will expand to show you its contents.. It only shows primitive types directly. (string, number, boolean, null, undefined). It just how the debugger works, nothing wrong with your code or how it is stored..

Comment: That’s just a short way to display it by the browser. Firefox does this too. In Firefox you can just click on “Array” to see the values.

Comment: (*btw. you could log the `JSON.stringify(nameCollection)` to see the full object printed*)

Comment: I'm just not sure why you titled the question `Javascript: Calling a function in an object literal` since you are really calling a function and assigning it to an Object property.

Answer (score 2):

The console displays it as Array[2] as it would be (potentially) unreadable if it expanded it fully. One way to see everything is to *stringify* it using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) which goes through each item in the object recursively and calls [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) on it:

```js
var myPets = ["Bengal Bobcat", "Beagle"];

var separateWords = function (string) {
    return string.split(" ");
};

var nameCollection = {};
nameCollection.cat = separateWords(myPets[0]);  
nameCollection.dog = myPets[1];
nameCollection.fish = null;

document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(nameCollection);
```

Comment: Holy cow, that may be the first time in a week I've seen someone use the inline code widget correctly.

Comment: I just came back after a long break and I think it's fantastic. `document.body.textContent` is your friend :)

Comment: No I mean a lot of people use it to highlight code, instead of simply *highlighting the code*. So running it does... nothing.

Comment: Yeah, all they need is to add the `document.body.textContent` line to make it output something usually.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to `cat` the result of the `separateWords()` function call, passing `myPets[0]` as a parameter.

`separateWords()` returns an array and with the `myPets[0]` input it returns a new array with the `"Bengal"` and `"Bobcat"` values splitted by the whitespace.

The split() function is the one creating an array with the splitted values and this result is returned by your `separateWords()` function, which also is the value assigned to the `cat` object member.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser implements its console like it wants.

So your browser decided to implement the behavior you describe.

If you don't like it, propose a better idea to the developers of this browser. Or use another browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are using Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug.

Developer tools condenses arrays and objects into easily readable lines you then inspect further with.  What I mean is, you push the little arrow next each line in the console log to further inspect each object.  I will use pictures to explain this.

Here I am assigning an array and then assigning an element in an object to that array as so:

[image]

As you can see when I log the object it show's an Array[2] rather than expand the array.  In this next picture I then expand the array to inspect it.

[image]

Why is this exactly?  My first thought is ease of readability.  If you have an app that is complex and you have numerous debugging console logs, you can see all the logs on single lines making it easier to hunt down specific logs.  As well, if you have a very large and complex object, it is arguably easier to read all the root elements on each line without expanding all the objects and arrays found within that object recursively.

Answer (score -1):

String.prototype.split() returns an array containing the two values in the string which have been split.  [Read through this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
nameCollection.cat = separateWords(myPets[0])[0]; // nameCollection.cat == Bengal
nameCollection.cat = separateWords(myPets[0])[1]; // nameCollection.cat == Bobcat
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn’t answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

This is simply how javascript (and many other languages) work.  When you try to print "nameCollection" javascript doesn't automatically do a nice job of printing the cat array.  Instead, it simply prints some type related information, which in this case is saying "cat" is an array of length 2.

Comment: No, this is not how ***JavaScript*** works, this is how the ***console ouput*** works.

Comment: Hey… if you deleted your answer you’d get the “Peer Pressure” bronze badge. =)